# Is there a way to view the number of unique views for a question on a mobile device?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, views, information-display

I'm using an iPhone, but I would imagine it's the same for other mobile devices as well. If you browse to any stack exchange site, you get a very well made mobile site. The only gripe that I have is that I can't find any way to view the number of visitors to my questions?

Am I missing something or could this possibly be integrated into the mobile renderer?

Comment: I think this issue may be no longer reproducible, since the mobile-specific site has been retired and the site now has a responsive design.

Comment: @V2Blast You are correct.  I see now that stnadard viewing on a mobile device shows this information.  I wish there was a Close option for "No longer relevant", since this is in fact no longer relevant.  Feel free to close/delete since you're an Admin.

Comment: MSE does have a community-specific reason for "no longer reproducible" issues. I'll close it now. :)

Answer (score 5):

Number of views is hidden on the mobile version of the site. Click on the *full site* link at the bottom of the page to view the desktop version of the site, then the number of views will be displayed on the right of the screen. Click on *mobile* in order to return to the mobile version.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that the browsers are detected whether if they were a mobile or a desktop browser, so that if it were a mobile device, the content downloaded will be smaller, less images and graphics to save you some bytes. This is important if you are using a mobile data plan.

The expected on any website that supports different devices is to provide all the details in all the devices, but in a different arrangement keeping the general look and feel. So in the stackoverflow website for mobile devices, I'm not sure if its meant to be like that, or its a small mistake, also the number of profile visitors is missing there btw.

Any way, to overcome that, some browsers settings can be modified to tell a server that they are a desktop browser not mobile, then it will load the page that you see usually on desktop browsers.

This also works in the other way around; in desktop browsers, firefox for example, you can install some plugins that will change the content view of your browser to a specified device.

All these tweeks are usually for testing, debugging.

I tested that using an application from *[Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=morrin.app.desktopbrowser)* called Desktop Browser, it is good, but ads of course  will annoy you sometimes

I'm sure there are tons of other applications, better than this one, but it works...

Hope this was useful.

Comment: There's also a link to the desktop version in the footer called "full site"

Comment: Nice, didn't notice it.  Anyway, this answer in generic, works for all websites :)