# Ask a question again, or there is a different way to get an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I wanted to ask a question similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139613/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-number-of-unique-views-for-a-question-on-a-mobile-dev), but it is from 2012 and does not have any answers or comments or anything.

So what's the suitable action in this case according to SE community? Asking it again?

Comment: The team have a lot on their plate, so it may simply be a question of priorities. I'll add a bounty to it to give it some renewed visibility.

Comment: In general, Meta feature requests often go unanswered when there isn't much to say about it.  As long as it doesn't have a red [status-*] tag, it means that it is still open (theoretically).  If you want to draw attention to it, then a bounty like @Pekka did is a good way to draw attention to an idea.

Comment: @pusbsee2003, thank you, it is helpful