# Number of views not available from an Android phone

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, views, information-display

When visiting any Stack Exchange site's mobile version from an Android device, the view counter is not displayed.

However, it is there on the full site view.

Comment: _Is it really avaialble?_ no I am changing tag to bug

Comment: @SagarV not a bug

Comment: @ItamarG3 oops, right. Sorry about the mess.

Comment: @Cai me getting confused. Thought this question here is about the android app (android in title got me confused), so reopened. (Someone notified me about the error, now he deleted the comment though.)

Comment: Fair enough, the duplicate wasn't about the app though? ..oh wait, you got confused but you can only use the dupehammer once?

Comment: Duplicate: [Is there a way to view the number of unique views for a question on a mobile device?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139613/307988)

Comment: @Cai I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked request applies to mobile-web, not the Android app.

Comment: @Steven this isn't about the app, it's about the mobile view; that's what Shadow Wizard got confused about

Comment: @Cai what is Shadow wizard?

Comment: @Saranjith the user who accidentally reopened this question after it was closed as a duplicate, see above comments

Comment: @Saranjith Shadow Wizard refers here in this context to a person, which also happens to be me.