# How can I view the actual number of views for a question?

Tags: support, views

Most questions on the SE websites tend to abbreviate their views above 1000 views. Meaning that a question with 1000 views shows it as "1k views", 10,000 views as "10k views" and so on.

But, is there a way to view the actual number of views on a question?

To clarify:

Suppose we have a question with 9,568 views. But, this is shown as "9k views" on the question.  I need to find a way to view the "9568 views" and not the "9k views" approximation.

Is there a way to view the actual number of views of a question?

This is not a duplicate of [Is there a way to view the number of unique views for a question on a mobile device?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139613/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-number-of-unique-views-for-a-question-on-a-mobile-dev) or [Number of views not available from an Android phone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299175/number-of-views-not-available-from-an-android-phone) because they ask about the deprecated mobile site. On the other hand, this question is asking about the modern responsive site.

Comment: For users that came here looking for an answer on how to do this on a touchscreen device: [Unable to view exact view count on questions with many views on touchscreen devices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387733)

Answer (score 4):

The exact number of views for a question (subject to caching) can be seen by hovering over the "Viewed X times" (where X can be an exact number of views for small view counts < 1000, or a rounded number in the form of 1k, 2k,... for larger view counts). Then, a popup hint will show up listing the exact number of views currently registered by the Stack Exchange engine.

Screenshot for a very active question on Meta — [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/383809):

[image]